# Getting error while installing node modules inside Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an angular app. When I am installing the `node modules` by running command `npm i --save` getting the following error.

> Error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
```

Here I am using `node version 10.x` and `angular version 7.3.6`. when I am trying to run the command `npm i --save`, these errors arises also `node_module` folder is empty. Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

ensure that your .npmrc file have this config :

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
always-auth=false
strict-ssl=false
```

Use below command to set registry:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If you are using a proxy to access the Web, then you also have to configure npm to use it:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyname:8080 
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxyname:8080
```